# Java : Compare all values of nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap of the following signature

```
Map<Key1, Map<Key2, List<Double>>>
```

I need to add the same index on the list across all keys of the inner nested map. I cannot seem to find any efficient way to do it as I would not be knowing the size of the list beforehand. 
Till now, the best I have come up with is converting all the inner lists into arraylists and then adding across all by the use of iterators. Can there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: "Add the same index on the list across all keys of the inner nested map" - are you filling the innermost list with the same value?  Could you give an example?  That's a bit unclear.

Comment: The values might be different, but the values at the same index need to be added. For instance for `Map<Key1, Map<Key21, [0.1 , 0.2]>>, Map<Key1, Map<Key22, [0.3, 0.4]>>` I'll have to add 0.1 and 0.3. Hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: @learningTheRopes Your question is unclear. Please post some sample input and output before the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Double sumOfSameIndex =0.0;    

Map<Key1, Map<Key2, List<Double>>> map = new LinkedHashMap<Key1, Map<Key2, List<Double>>>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<Key1, Map<Key2, List<Double>>>> outerIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();


        while(outerIterator.hasNext()){

        Map.Entry<Key1, Map<Key2, List<Double>>> entryForOuterMap= outerIterator.next();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<Key2, List<Double>>> innerIterator = entryForOuterMap.getValue().entrySet().iterator();

           while(innerIterator.hasNext()){

                Map.Entry<Key2, List<Double>> entryForInnerMap = innerIterator.next();

           // entryForInnerMap.getValue() returns List<Double> 
           List<Double> getList= entryForInnerMap.getValue(); 

                // REPLACE THIS x WITH the INDEX OF ARRAY YOU WANT TO SUM 
              sumOfSameIndex = sumOfSameIndex + getList.get ( x );  

          }
     }
```